# What is the jQuery equivalent of a CSS media query?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jQuery mobile to create a sidepanel. I have the following code, which adds swipe functionality to reveal the sidepanel:

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#swipe-page", function() {
    $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#swipe-page", function( e ) {
        // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
        // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
        // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
        if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
            if ( e.type === "swipeleft" ) {
                $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
            } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
                $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I only want this swipe enabled when the user has a viewport of 480px or greater. How can I add this? In CSS the effect would be created via a media query.

Comment: You could try `$("body").width()` to get the size, then react accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Tim, as simple as `if($("body").width() = 480`? How would cross browser fare under this?

Comment: As far as I know it should be fine. You might have issues with the scrollbar width sometimes being taken into account and sometimes not(I seem to remember reading something like that somewhere). and it would be `if($("body").width() >= 480)` you forgot the `>`

Comment: I'd remove the php tag If I were you. This has nothing to do with php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those interested, here's the hack I eventually used:

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#swipe-page", function() {
    $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#swipe-page", function( e ) {
element (panel: open).
if($('#mobile-view').is(":visible")) {
        if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
            if ( e.type === "swipeleft" ) {
                $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
            } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
                $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
            }
        }
}
    });
});
```

Essentially, I created an element that was subject to a CSS media query, then I tested the visibility of that element in jQuery. This ensures better cross-browser compatability, and it should update for mobile on resolution change.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing I can think of to do this is

```
if($("body").width() >= 480) {
     //I'm a big boy now, swipe me

     //swiping code here
} else {
     //I am small: swiper no swiping, swiper no swiping, swiper no swiping.

     //do something else here if you want.
}
```

I think you shouldn't have any issues with different browsers, but as always for this type of thing you should test extensively on your important platforms.

This won't react in the same exact way as a media query. For example, it doesn't (directly) support modifying behavior when the screen size changes.

Comment: Thanks, why use something like enquire.js then? Am I missing the point of this loader? http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js.

Comment: @alias51 That might be a good alternative. This is a gun to my head, bare bones answer. With a tool like that you can do fancier things and don't have to think as much about how to accomplish it. If all you need is width queries, I think my solution is very usable and doesn't require an extra dependency. YMMV.